# $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is empty after redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, redirect

I don't want to allow users to type the URLs manually in web browser.
It may lead to hacking attacks.
So if the http referer is empty, it should redirect to home page.

I write this php code in drupal web application's index.php.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "")
{
    header("Location:http://mysite.com"); 
}
```

The problem is that the loop continues infinitely. It never shows the home page.
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is always empty.

In Firefox, I get the below error.
The page isn't redirecting properly
 Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Anybody wanting to hack your site can easily spoof the refer header and there are plenty of legitimate situations where that header won't be sent. Give up on this approach.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER won't be blank, if the "hackers" are requesting your website, from theirs, so it won't save you from "hacking attacks", also it's giving you additional headache, according to your post. Consider changing the way.

Comment: Learn basic web security and you can easily solve this.

Comment: ok. One doubt.

What will the value of $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] in index.php [after redirecting from header("Location:http://localhost") ]?

Comment: No doubt. php.net's doc: `Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: The code you posted is doing its job. If people are trying to access the root of your website without a referer, of course it will loop forever. Replace `header("Location:http://mysite.com");` that points to a different page on your server `header("Location:http://mysite.com/bad_referer.php");` and of course, create a page called `bad_referer.php` with some content in it telling them so. This should be an answer instead of a comment actually. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is doing its job. If people are trying to access the root of your website without a referer, of course it will loop forever.

Replace `header("Location:http://mysite.com");` that points to a different page on your server `header("Location:http://mysite.com/no_referer.php");` and of course, create a page called `no_referer.php` with some content in it telling them so.

Since the code is constantly checking if the referer is from your site, there needs to be three different pages and they are as follows:

1. index.php *(assuming that's what your index file is called)*
2. welcome.php
3. no_referer.php

One for the index, one for welcome access and one for a bad referer.

Try this instead and give it a condition.

(Inside your index.php file)

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "")
{
    header("Location:http://mysite.com/no_referer.php");
exit;
}

else {
    header("Location:http://mysite.com/welcome.php");
exit;   
}
?>
```

And to test with an `href`, use the following and create a page called `test_referer.php` which will act as your `index.php` file.

```
<a href="referer_test.php">Referer test</a>
```

Then copy the code above (`the code that checks for a referer`) into a file called `referer_test.php`, and create the other pages accordingly called `no_referer.php` and `welcome.php` with respective content inside.

Comment: There shouldn't be three pages... After the following piece of code, Gurunathan can continue his index page as usual: if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "")
{
    header("Location: http://example.com/no_referer.php");
exit;
}

Comment: Sometimes the referer is not set at all, so this will fail $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "", it should be isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) && !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])

Answer (score 1):

The correct check should be:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) && !empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]))
{
   ... do something with referer
}
```

Because $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == " will give an error when the referer is not set.